# lower bound for $\vert a+b\vert^\alpha$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b$ be two positives real numbers and $\alpha >1$, by convexity we know that $$\vert a+b\vert^\alpha\le 2^{\alpha-1}(\vert a\vert^\alpha+\vert b\vert^\alpha).$$

But is it possible to have a lower bound ? I mean, does there for every $\alpha > 1$ exist a constant $K_{\alpha} > 0$, such that $\vert a+b\vert^\alpha\ge K_\alpha(\vert a\vert^\alpha+\vert b\vert^\alpha)$, for all positive real $A$ and $b$.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be explicit about what property/ies you expect from this lower bound ? Because the formula $|a+b|^\alpha$ is extremely simple and I can't see how you could "improve" it. $a+b$ is a trivial lower bound.

Comment: As the values are positive, the absolute value operators are useless.

Comment: You said "something like...", which is wide open.

Comment: Do you mean additively, i.e. $f(a)+f(b)$ ?

Comment: You are not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(t)=t^{\alpha}+(1-t)^{\alpha}$ for $t \in [0,1]$. Then $f$ attains its minimum at $t =\frac 1 2$ and the minimum value is $2^{1-\alpha}$. Hence $f(t) \geq 2^{1-\alpha}$ for all $t$. The upper bound you have stated is obtained by putting $t=\frac {|a|} {|a|+|b|}$. Since $f(t) \leq 2$ we also have an inequality in the opposite direction: $|a+b|^{\alpha} \geq \frac  1 2 (|a|^{\alpha}+|b|^{\alpha})$.

Also, $2^{\alpha-1}$ is the best constant in the upper bound because equality holds whene $a=b=1$.

Comment: thanks, small typo $|a+b|^{\alpha} \geq \frac  1 2 (|a|^{\alpha}+|b|^{\alpha})$.

Comment: @TTL Thanks. Corrected.