# Estimating $|a+b|^p$ for real $p$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove the estimate for $a,b\in \mathbb{R^n}, p\geq 1$
$$|a+b|^p\leq C(|a|^p+|b|^p)$$
where $C$ is a constant depending only on $p$.

I am able to do it when $p$ is a natural number. But, could you give me any hints on how to do it for any $p\geq 1$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3196836/42969, $C=2^{p-1}$ is the best constant.

Comment: Dividing by $|a|^p$ you need the inequality: $$|1+x|^p\leq C(1+|x|^p)$$ Not sure if that helps. You can pick $|a|\leq |b|$ so $|x|\geq 1.$ Trying $x=1,$ this shows that you need $C\geq 2^{p-1}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews And in fact $C\ge 2^{p-1}$ is sufficient, as $\frac{(1+|x|)^p}{1+|x|^p} $ attains its maximum at $x=1$, and $|1+x |^p \le (1+|x| )^p$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143173/321264